# 99% of questions answered?

Tags: discussion

I was looking at [the initial proposal for Moderators.SE on Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/52070/moderators) and I saw the statistics. 1 question per day, 99% answered, .. wait, what? 99.9% answered? Oh no! There are no questions for me to answer! This sucks. This makes Webmasters.SE less fun!

(*Please note that I'm using sarcasm*)

But joking aside, I think that's great. Good job and keep up the good work, guys!

Comment: The irony is nobody has answered this meta post in 11 hours...

Comment: You could answer [this one](http://moderators.stackexchange.com/q/619/83). :-)

Comment: Mission Accomplished @MonicaCellio. 100% Cookies for everyone!

Comment: @Andy OK :) http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6e/Pepperidge-Farm-Nantucket-Cookie.jpg

Comment: @Andy and what a good answer, too!